# Terminate a process of a process tree in command line (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, kill

I am in need of a command that will allow me to terminate a process of a process tree.

For example `notepad.exe` was created by explorer. How would I terminate the `notepad.exe` in the `explorer.exe` process tree ?

Answer (score 9):

This answer is not exactly for this case, but it can be useful for people looking how to kill the whole process tree. We need to combine some answers here to get the proper result: kill the process tree and force it.

`taskkill /IM "<process-name>" /T /F`

For some processes you need to run the command in a console application with administrator rights.

Answer (score 6):

Use `taskkill /IM <processname.exe> /T`.

Comment: Thats not what I want to do at all

Comment: :) it was specified but hidden, because it is not put as code

Comment: Wouldn't that kill all the notepad.exe's processes ? Also question is to kill notepad.exe under some particular parent process.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, you can do this with PowerShell:

```ps1
$cimProcesses = Get-CimInstance -Query "select ProcessId, ParentProcessId from Win32_Process where Name = 'notepad.exe'"
$processes = $cimProcesses | Where-Object { (Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId).ProcessName -eq "explorer" } | ForEach-Object { Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId }

$processes.Kill()
```

Or the graceful way:

```ps1
$cimProcesses = Get-CimInstance -Query "select ProcessId, ParentProcessId from Win32_Process where Name = 'notepad.exe'"
$cimProcesses = $cimProcesses | Where-Object { (Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId).ProcessName -eq "explorer" }

$cimProcesses | ForEach-Object { taskkill /pid $_.ProcessId }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe
```

This would kill all `notepad.exe`'s -- if you want a way to specify to only kill `notepad.exe`'s which were created by `foo.exe` or so, I do not think Windows command lines are powerful enough for this.

You might can use `tasklist` to get the process ID of the process you want to target and then use `taskkill /F /PID <PID>` to kill it.

Answer (score 2):

Try PsKill + PsList utilities from the [PsTools set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649).

`pslist -t` will give you a process tree (here you can find `notepad.exe` which is a child process of the `explorer.exe`. Then you can use `pskill` to kill the process with specified id.